# Locking async method in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, locking, windows-phone, async-await

I am uploading data to dropbox on a button Command using custom method name UploadDataToDropbboxAsync(); i am using this method on like this.

```
 RelayCommand _navigateToDropBoxUploadCommand;
    public ICommand NavigateToDropBoxUploadCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _navigateToDropBoxUploadCommand = _navigateToDropBoxUploadCommand ?? new RelayCommand(
                    async () =>
                    {
                        await UploadDataToDropbox("sandbox");
                    });
        }
    }
```

so when i click the button multiple time before wait for data to be uploaded then thr is multiple simultaneous uploads happening.
so i wanted to put a lock on this method such that it will not be called again before first upload finished.
any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use locking for this.  For one, you're only dealing with one thread--the UI thread (at least in terms of the locking--as what you're really asking is to lock-out the UI thread from running this command).  Another, it's heavy-weight compared do what would be a better way of dealing with this.

I would simply disable the button before the Async and re-enable it afterwards.  For example:

```
return _navigateToDropBoxUploadCommand = _navigateToDropBoxUploadCommand ?? new RelayCommand(
    async () =>
    {
        myButton.IsEnabled = false;
        await UploadDataToDropbox("sandbox");
        myButton.IsEnabled = true;
    });
```

But, the disabling of the button may better done somewhere else, depending on how you're handling commands, etc... (e.g. if you're reusing this command for several UI tap/click events).

Comment: peter i know this way..but i just want a proper way may be it's not locking but something else.as it is handled manually i think there will be some method or in asynv/await usage library. thanks for your reply

Comment: That *is* the way--to simply disable a portion of a UI so that it cannot perform the same action at the same time.  Any other "locking" would cause your UI to appear hung and be a bad user experience.  The only way to get around the "hung" appearance would be to disable the button and circumvent the locking...

Comment: Hi @Peter , I have read about the AsyncLock and i found that it will lock the async method but it put the calls to this method into a queue and that will definitely will be a problem. so your solution is right.

Answer (score 0):

With an AsyncLock its possible to create a upload queue instead of simultaneous uploads:

```
private readonly AsyncLock _dropBoxUploadLock = new AsyncLock(); 

return _navigateToDropBoxUploadCommand = _navigateToDropBoxUploadCommand ?? new RelayCommand(
    async () =>
    {   
        var cachedStateFromUI = GetDataFromTheUI(...);
        using(var releaser = await _dropBoxUploadLock.LockAsync()) 
        {
            await UploadDataToDropbox(cachedStateFromUI);
        }
    });
```

The AsyncLock class used is from the example of Stephen Toub  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266988.aspx

```
  /*
   * private readonly AsyncLock m_lock = new AsyncLock(); 
   * … 
   * using(var releaser = await m_lock.LockAsync()) 
   * { 
   *     … // protected code here 
   * }
   */

  /// <summary>
  /// http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266988.aspx
  /// </summary>
  public class AsyncLock
  {
    private readonly AsyncSemaphore m_semaphore;
    private readonly Task<Releaser> m_releaser;

    public AsyncLock()
    {
      m_semaphore = new AsyncSemaphore(1);
      m_releaser = Task.FromResult(new Releaser(this));
    }

    public Task<Releaser> LockAsync()
    {
      var wait = m_semaphore.WaitAsync();
      return wait.IsCompleted ?
          m_releaser :
          wait.ContinueWith((_, state) => new Releaser((AsyncLock)state),
              this, CancellationToken.None,
              TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    public struct Releaser : IDisposable
    {
      private readonly AsyncLock m_toRelease;

      internal Releaser(AsyncLock toRelease) { m_toRelease = toRelease; }

      public void Dispose()
      {
        if (m_toRelease != null)
          m_toRelease.m_semaphore.Release();
      }
    } 
  }
```

The AsyncLock depends on the AsyncSemaphore http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266983.aspx

```
  /*
   * private readonly AsyncSemaphore m_lock = new AsyncSemaphore(1); 
   * … 
   * await m_lock.WaitAsync(); 
   * try 
   * { 
   *     … // protected code here 
   * }  
   * finally { m_lock.Release(); }
   */

  /// <summary>
  /// http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266983.aspx
  /// </summary>
  public class AsyncSemaphore
  {
    private readonly static Task s_completed = Task.FromResult(true);
    private readonly Queue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>> m_waiters = new Queue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();
    private int m_currentCount;

    public AsyncSemaphore(int initialCount)
    {
      if (initialCount < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("initialCount");
      m_currentCount = initialCount;
    }

    public Task WaitAsync()
    {
      lock (m_waiters)
      {
        if (m_currentCount > 0)
        {
          --m_currentCount;
          return s_completed;
        }
        else
        {
          var waiter = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
          m_waiters.Enqueue(waiter);
          return waiter.Task;
        }
      }
    }

    public void Release()
    {
      TaskCompletionSource<bool> toRelease = null;
      lock (m_waiters)
      {
        if (m_waiters.Count > 0)
          toRelease = m_waiters.Dequeue();
        else
          ++m_currentCount;
      }
      if (toRelease != null)
        toRelease.SetResult(true);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm afraid, that would not work on wp7. I dont remember what exactly, but something is not existed in Bcl.Async. I guess, wait.ContinueWith() - i tried it some time ago, but i didnt success.